# Load single objects from "index" allways

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using the latest revision of Ember-Data and the RESTAdapter, is there a way of doing the following?

I have a resource called `App` and a API that responds to `/apps` by returning the correct JSON (with `{ apps: [...] }`etc.)

Since this gets served from a static json on our server, it is quiet inappropriate to create server-side resources for every app that can be fetched as `/apps/:app_id`. Instead, it would be good if the RESTAdapter *allways* loaded `/apps`, even if it then only uses one single app out of the fetched ones.

Do I have to write my own Adapter to achieve this? If yes, what would be a good point to "hook into"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a little hacky (and probably is), but it looks like one can achieve this by overwriting the `DS.Adapter:find()`.

In my case, to block calls to `/app/:app_id` I wrote this:

```
find: function(store, type, id) {
    // Terminate calls for single app
    if (type === App.App) {
        // instead, load all apps and drop this request
        App.App.find();
        return;
    }
    // or continue as usual
    this._super(store, type, id);
 }
```

This also works when you have a hierarchy of embedded: 'always' records and Ember thinks it has to load a middle level. Just make sure you load the parent for sure when dropping requests like this!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have an app model `App.App`, it should be enough to call `App.App.find()` when your application loads. This will make the AJAX call to `/apps`. Even if you don't cache the result in a variable, your data store will be populated with the returned records. Now whenever you call `App.App.find(id)`, Ember Data will check your store and return the record if it has it. If it doesn't have the record, then it will try to call `/apps/:id`, but this shouldn't happen if your application is designed to use only a static collection.

There are a few different places you could put the `App.App.find()` call. I would probably put it in `App.ready`:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    // pre-load apps
    App.App.find();
  }
});

App.App = DS.Model.extend({
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Doing so will still fire a request to `/apps/:app_id` (which is due to the `model()` function in the route I think), but it seems fine to return a 404 and have the data loaded from `/apps`.Would be still interesting to know if there is a cleaner way to do `Model.find(id)` without firing a special request so I'm leaving this open for now.